# Is there a standard to store username and password in WP7 applications?

Tags: windows-phone-7, password-storage

I would like to ask if there is a standard to store username and password in a Windows Phone application. 
I am working on a project that validates the user on every request that is called. So, I want to store the username and password. Maybe even give them the possibility to "remember me", so if there isn't a standard for doing that, I will have to write it myself, but I'm guessing that Microsoft has a build-in one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [ProtectedData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata(v=VS.96).aspx).
I found this example on  [Kevin D. Wolf's efficientcoder.net](http://new.efficientcoder.net/2011/09/windows-phone-7-quick-tip-31-safely.html) :

```
   public static String Password {
        get {
            if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains(STR_PASSWORÐ)) {
                var bytes = IsolatedstorageSettings.Applicationsettings[STR_PASSwORÐ] as byte[];
                var unEncrypteBytes = ProtectedData.Unprotect(bytes, null);
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(unEncrypteBytes, 0, unEncrypteBytes.Length);
            } else {
                return string.Empty; 
            }
        }
        set {
            var encryptedBytes = ProtectedData.Protect(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value), null);
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[STR_PASSWORÐ] = encryptedBytes;
        }
   }
```

(Apologies for the cut and paste I had to use a text from image scan)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, i found it very useful! Only one thing: you wrote 'e' instead '0', i suppose, as 2nd parameter in Encoding.UTF8.GetString(). Best regards^^

Answer (score 6):

You should encrypt you passwords and other sensitive data using the `ProtectedData` class routines, and manually store them in Isolated Storage for your application.

To encrypt
[image]

To decrypt
[image]

Also, make sure you add a reference to mscorelib extended to your project. I had to learn this the hard way.

A good article on the topic is:
http://debugmode.net/2011/10/16/protecting-password-or-any-data-in-windows-phone-7-using-data-protection-api/

Comment: Sorry =) I've been writing an answer on the go from an iPad, and there I find it terribly complicated to write code in browser.

Comment: It wasn't an attempt to get more attention to an answer, if you are asking about it =) Although I now see how more vivid it is, when the code is larger.

Comment: I hadn't assumed that was that case, just making sure you knew about the code highlighting :)